# Objects' IDs by common value in different variables

Tags: r

I have a dataset with self-ratings and peer-ratings. The dataset is in long format. Before reshaping the dataset into wide-format, I want to give self-ratings and peer-ratings a common ID so that I can later match the peer-ratings to the self-ratings by that ID. The data look like this:

```
| questionnaire | ID | REF  | SERIAL | x  | y  |
|---------------|----|------|--------|----|----|
| self          | 1  | 1234 | NA     | 4  | NA |
| self          | 2  | 2345 | NA     | 6  | NA |
| peer          | NA | NA   | 1234   | NA | 8  |
| peer          | NA | NA   | 2345   | NA | 4  |
```

The self-ratings have a reference variable ("REF") which refer to a peer-rating. The peer-ratings have the same value in the variable "SERIAL".

I'm now trying to attribute the same ID to the peer-ratings as the ID of the self-ratings which refer to the peers by the SERIAL value. The table should look like this then:

```
| questionnaire | ID | REF  | SERIAL | x  | y  |
|---------------|----|------|--------|----|----|
| self          | 1  | 1234 | NA     | 4  | NA |
| self          | 2  | 2345 | NA     | 6  | NA |
| peer          | 1  | NA   | 1234   | NA | 8  |
| peer          | 2  | NA   | 2345   | NA | 4  |
```

How could I do this best?

Comment: Please put data in R format. Best is output from `dput`.

Comment: Are the IDs always only available for the "self" ratings? Will "self" and "peer" always have the same number of rows and a definite 1-to-1 match?

Comment: Thank you for editing my first post here :) No, "self" and "peer" don't have the same number of rows. For some self reports, there are even multiple peer reports (up to three). So actually there are three REF variables in the dataset, but for illustration I only included one.

Answer (score 0):

may I can help you. I would like to change the ID values right in the data frame. For that I would do a loop around the rows by picking up an ID from the right counterpart and adding it into the NA's in the data frame. In my following code example, I've searched for the right ID for every peer. The **map_df** function does the loop and prepares as a  output a data frame.

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

marcel.data <- data.frame(questionnaire = c("self", "self", "peer", "peer"),
                      ID = c(1, 2, NA, NA),
                      REF = c("1234", "2345", NA, NA),
                      SERIAL = c(NA, NA, "1234", "2345"),
                      x = c(4, 6, NA, NA),
                      y = c(NA, NA, 8, 4))


new_id_data <- map_df(1:nrow(marcel.data), function(i){

 if(marcel.data[i, 1] == "peer") { # matching peer to Self
  serial <- unique(marcel.data[i, "SERIAL"])  

  new.id <- marcel.data %>%     # getting the needed ID
   filter(REF == serial & questionnaire == "self") %>%
   select(ID)

  marcel.data[i, "ID"] <- new.id  # adding the new ID to the old data

  marcel.data[i,] 

 } else
  (marcel.data[i,])

})
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Your solution totally worked with the dataset I posted here. Unfortunately, it didn't work in my real data (error: replacement has length zero). The data I posted here was a simple one, cause I didn't want to make it too uncomplicated. I wasn't aware that that might be a problem. Totally my fault, I'm sorry. 
I'm gonna post a real extract of my data, so it might be easier to transfer the solution to my real data.